# PHP/JQUERY / AJAX: Keyboard's Arrow Down Or Up Disappears and Enter Button Not Working with a List Autocomplete

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, autocomplete

I am a newbie to JQUERY / AJAX, and I really need some help figuring this out due to I have been working on this problem for over a week with no success.  I've got a search box that has a keyup function bound to it where it does an autocomplete for jurisdictions and cities which is retrieving from a database. The results appear in a div right below the search box with in an unorder list of results.

What I need it to do is if someone hits the down arrow on a keyboard the the focus gets switched to the div element which has the ul. Then it can move up and down in the list and they can hit enter as well. I am able to use the mouse to select in the list.  I have tried coding myself, which I was able to arrow down the first few items, but then it seems the cursor disappears after 30 second, and it will not scroll down or up the through the entire ul list.  Most importantly, when I hit enter, nothing happens.

I cannot and will not use the JUI Autocomplete, because I am pulling up a hidden field in the php portion, which if I use the autocomplete and use json, I cannot get the same effect. So please do not suggest the jui Autocomplete, unless you are able to re-code my php and my jquery. I even tried using keydown, and keypress within my code or even change the keyup to keydown but just doesn't seem to work.

I Truely and desperatly need your help.  I am completely lost and frustrated. I am using wordpress has my bases if that gives you and ideas to move forward.

My code below...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search-box").keyup(function(e){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/VCSWeb/wp-content/themes/i-excel-child/autocomplete.php",
        data:'keyword='+$(this).val(),
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF url(LoaderIcon.gif) no-repeat 165px");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#suggesstion-box ").show();
            $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
            $("#search-box").css("background","#FFF");
        }
        });
        if(e.which == 40){
            if($("#suggesstion-box li.active").length!=0) {
                var storeTarget = $('#suggesstion-box').find("li.active").next();
                $("#suggesstion-box li.active").removeClass("active");
                storeTarget.focus().addClass("active");
            }
            else {
                $('#suggesstion-box').find("li:first").focus().addClass("active");
            }
            return ;
        }
        if(e.which == 38){
            if($("#suggesstion-box li.active").length!=0) {
                var storeTarget = $('#suggesstion-box').find("li.active").prev();
                $("#suggesstion-box li.active").removeClass("active");
                storeTarget.focus().addClass("active");
            }
            else {
                $('#suggesstion-box').find("li:first").focus().addClass("active");
            }
            return ;
        }
        if(e.which == 13){
            if($("#suggesstion-box li.active").length!=0) {
                var storeTarget = $('#suggesstion-box').find("li.active").prev();
                $("#suggesstion-box li.active").removeClass("active");
                storeTarget.focus().addClass("active");
            }
            else {
                $('#suggesstion-box').find("li:first").focus().addClass("active");
            }
            return ;
        }

    });
});

function selectCountry(val) {
  $("#search-id").val(val);
  $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}

function updateSearchBox(el) {
  $("#search-box").val($(el).html());   
}


</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<style>
#suggesstion-box li{    
    list-style:none;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    padding: 10px; 
    background-color:#FAFAFA; 
    border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid; 
    transition:all 0.5s;
      -moz-transition:all 0.5s;
      -webkit-transition:all 0.5s;
      cursor:pointer; 
      word-wrap:break-word;
 }
#suggesstion-box li:hover, #country-list li:focus{ background:#F0F0F0; }
#suggesstion-box li.active { background:#000; color:#fff; }
#suggesstion-box {
    position: absolute;  
    display:block; 
    top:80;
    left:0;
    width:600px; 
    z-index:9999;
    float:left; 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    width: 50%; 
    }
#search-box{padding: 10px;border: #F0F0F0 1px solid;}

.placeholder
{
    position: relative;
}

.placeholder::after
{
    position: absolute;
    left:150px;
    top: 10px;
    font-size:18px;
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
</style>
<form role="search" name="remarks_lookup" id="myForm" method="post" class="search-form" action="/VCSWeb/remarks-look-up/" >
    <div style="background-color:#ffffff; width:100%; float:left;  padding-bottom:25px; clear:both;  ">
        <div class="frmSearch " style="width:90%; float:left;"   >
            <label>                                             
                <input  type="search" name="jurisdiction_search"  class="search_keyword" id="search-box" placeholder="Enter Jurisdiction, County, City, or Client Name" autocomplete="off" />
                <input type="hidden" name="search" id="search-id"  />
                 <div class="box" id="suggesstion-box"></div>
            </label>
        </div>

        <div style="width:10%; float:left; clear:right;">
            <label>                                         
                <input style="width:100%; height: 50px; " type="submit"  value="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Search', 'submit button' ) ?>" />
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the PHP Portion.  I have added the code that is in the autocomplete.php with the exceptions of the pulling the database and query code:

```
    if (!$result){
            echo "<div class='show' align='left'>No matching records.</div>";
    }else {
        ?>
        <ul id="country-list" class="dropdown-menu" tabindex="0" role="menu" >
        <?php
        while($row=pg_fetch_assoc($result)){
        ?>
              <li  tabindex="10" class="selectable" onClick="selectCountry('<?php echo $row["cid"]; ?>'); updateSearchBox(this);" > <?php echo "(".$row["cid"].") ".$row["organization"].", ".$row["state"]; ?> </li>
        <?php } ?>
        </ul>

        <?php
    }
```

I Truely and desperatly need your help.  I am completely lost and frustrated. PLEASE HELP me solve this issue.  I m not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: If I press "down" arrow mine seem to go to the "selection-box" options - [Check this Codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/JbdPxp)

Comment: Could it be the PHP portion causing it to disappear after 30 seconds and not stay on and go through the entire list?  I have added the php portion to above...  
Or could it be the onClick feature due to the hidden value which is updateSearchBox(this) giving us grief?

Comment: This is incomplete code, I cant help you much with this. I have no idea what data does `/VCSWeb/wp-content/themes/i-excel-child/autocomplete.php` return. Can you perhaps give a link to your website where I could easily pinpoint the issue to you ?

Comment: Disappear after 30 seconds ? Anyway you could replicate that for me?

Comment: I have added the code that is in the autocomplete.php with the exceptions of the pulling the database and query code

Comment: I start typing two letters of "jo", and a list popsup below.  I hit the arrow key down once and it changes the background to grey, hit it twice and changes the background grey.  Then, background disappears, and then the mouser (without touching it) appears with the pointer cursor and goes back to top of list.  I hit down arrow again, the page moves down but mouse cursor stays put. Hit down arrow again, again same thing happens.  I hit the end of the last or page cannot scroll down any more and it seems stuck.  I can scroll up if page permits me. Try to hit enter, and enter not working neither.

Comment: Yes I understand but to debug a complicated issue like this I need a replica of the problem. I don't even have a dummy data to work on in the first place. All the problems are to do with the popup, which doesn't even exist for me! So **unless you give me a link to your project hosted somewhere or atleast replicate it somewhere I can't really help you** Sorry

Comment: It seems that after a short time, it reverts back to the mouse cursor for some strange reason.  Like I mention above, it hightlights the when arrowing down for a short while but then it reverts back to mouse causing the cursor to pop up so when you use the arrow key it keeps the cursor placed (where it last was) but moves the screen.

Comment: I can email you the link to the autocomplete file...

Comment: I have a fiddle with it leading to the autocomplete file, or  I can send you the the autocomplete file link.  Will that work???

Comment: The autocomplete file won't be helpful for me .. I don't have a PHP setup anyways. I would need a live replica of your problem. I will add PHP tag as well to your question. This will help you reach a lot more people hopefully finding an answer .. ok ? :)

Comment: You could add the autocomplete here in this [Codepen](http://codepen.io/PleaseBugMeNot/pen/JbdPxp) & replicate your problem.

Comment: If I could send you my code pages, will that help?  If so, let me know where can I send it too?  I can highlight the parts...